# forgetting root password

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, passwords

I tried to access my folder but warning say you are not root and and permission area doesnot clearly open that is I couldnot access its feature to change its permission and sudo is not accessible Moreover, sudo nautilus is not useable warning is e1630862 is not in the sudoers file. how can I access

FAQ:
Are you logged in with the same user account that was created when the system was installed?
answer yes
FGA:
You'll need to find your root password, login as root and then do your thing.
I forget my password

Feel free , if you have other advise

Answer (score 2):

[How-To Recover password under Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-recover-password-under-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 1):

You may boot Linux to init 1 and log in as root without password: Just add parameter "single" to kernel in grub (press esc, press e, add, press b) during booting. Then root's password can be changed by passwd.